# Any "faster" methods of backing up databases in mariadb?

Tags: mariadb, tokudb

I am coming from the Microsoft SQL Server world of databases, and have been there for about 7 years. My new role is solely based in various open source database engines.

As I have been prepping for some migrations to AWS RDS and/or newer versions of MariaDB, I have come up on an issue regarding a backup strategy for my company. ATM, and to spare the sensitive details, there isn't any solution in place. The databases that are the biggest concern are all running on older TokuDB storage engines, and are the ones in question that will need to be migrated. Backing up these databases has been done mainly through the following method instead of piping the whole database into one .sql file

mysqldump -u root -p -t -T/$source $database $databasetable --fields-terminated-by='|' --lines-terminated-by='\n' --order-by-primary

I could simply just say to backup the whole db and have it spit out each table one at a time, but regardless, this takes several hours. Doing a plain sql dump, whether that is using gzip or not, takes 24+ hours, if not more. This is clearly not the best for having a standard backup strategy like you could find with Ola Hallengren's Maintenance Plan for Microsoft SQL Server.However, the only alternative I could think of is writing something in python or using a cronjob to execute the backups on a schedule that has yet to be determined.

The only solution I found was Percona's XtraBackup, but wanted to see if the community had other ideas.

**More background:**

These are database servers running as EC2 instances in AWS, on Ubuntu and are provisioned as m4.large or m4.xlarge.

There are several replica's of the primary, so the backup would ideally be done ON the primary, not the replica

**Final mentions**
Yes-migrating to RDS is an option, which would eliminate this issue with automated backups. However, the migration of these older Tokudb servers is not going to be "that" easy, so it may be some time before we get there.

I would appreciate any input or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: What is the goal?  To move the data to a new or different platform?  (SOL)  Or to be able to recover from a bad crash?  (use LVM)

Comment: Both technically. 1) for current state it is to implement backups in case or corruption or crash. The future state is to migrate data to a new source, regardless if it is another EC2 instances or RDS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Percona XtraBackup is a hot backup tool for InnoDB tables. It won't do squat for TokuDB or any other storage engine.

Percona also makes a hot backup tool for TokuDB: https://docs.percona.com/percona-server/8.0/tokudb/toku_backup.html

Both tools have caveats if you have a mixed environment, with some tables in both storage engines. Read the documentation carefully and do lots of testing.

Another option for a fast backup is to use an LVM snapshot. I recommend checking out [mylvmbackup](https://launchpad.net/mylvmbackup), which is just a handy script that wraps the multiple steps needed to make an LVM snapshot.

Regardless of storage engine, another piece of general advice applies: *drop any data you don't need to store in this database.*

In many databases I have analyzed, a lot of data is ripe for archiving, and then removing from the database. If you make your live database instance smaller, then any backup solution will be easier to manage. You don't have to destroy the data permanently, but move it to some cheaper storage.

Comment: And that is just it, 90 percent is achievable data. The problem is our customers want to pull from that archived data. My thought would be essentially offload archive data into a separate instance and when the API call is made, it will either direct to recent or to archived. There are some.more complexities I am leaving out but it's totally doable

Comment: Archive-able my apologies

Comment: Good plan. Yes, it should be pretty straightforward to manage two database connections in the application.

Comment: @theRetroDBA Re: archiving and cheaper storage, there is a S3 storage engine (read-only) in MariaDB 10.5 and later, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-the-s3-storage-engine/

Comment: @dbdemon, I don't use MariaDB, but that makes me wonder about how that interacts with backup tools. Would a backup tool download the entire data content you had stored on S3?

Comment: It can, MariaDB's mysqldump has an option --copy-s3-tables which will initially dump the tables as Aria tables, then ALTER them to become S3. There is also the separate aria_s3_copy tool which can copy to and from Aria.

Comment: @BillKarwin looking into S3 storage engine, my only concern is the archived data still needs to be accessed regularly. Most of the time, clients are looking for recent data (within 24hours) or data within the current month. Though, we get requests throughout the day looking for historical data....whether that is a full year, 3 months, or data from a source dating back to 1997. I will certainly have to test the read speeds of s3. If it is passable, it will make my life easier to offload archive data to one or two ec2 instances running mariadb/s3 storage engine.

Comment: That's up to you and the requirements for your project. There are solutions to read data from S3, for example the MariaDB storage engine, or something like AWS Athena (but be careful with Athena, do some pricing models, because you pay _per query_ and per data volume). You might also look into other AWS products like Redshift or DynamoDB that are meant for high-scale data.